# Modularize an ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have classes like this,

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExampleModule
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExampleModule
end

module ExampleModule
  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end      

  def included(base)
    ...
  end
end
```

how do I get the a reference to class A or B inside of ExampleModule upon referencing including this module into either one of those classes? I'm asking this question because I wanted to do something like adding **has_one :association** or **after_create :do_something** to class A or B via including ExampleModule such as below.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExampleModule
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExampleModule
end

module ExampleModule
  has_one :association
  after_create :do_something      

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end      

  def included(base)
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), you should be able to do it when the module is `included`:

```
module ExampleModule

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def do_something
    # ...
  end

  included do
    has_one :association
    after_create :do_something      
  end
end
```

Comment: I was expecting something different but your answer is better than my expectation. Thanks!

Comment: Does ActiveSupport::Concern also work for controllers as well? Like adding before_filter, etc?

Comment: I guess it probably would, but I've only ever used `Concern` with models. (checks documentation)...actually, it looks like it would be fair game (see http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/)

Answer (score 1):

If what you're wanting to do is call `has_one` or `after_create` depending on which class is including the module you can do this

```
module Extender
  def self.included(base)
    if base.name == A.name
       # do stuff for A
       has_one :association
    elsif base.name == B.name
       # do stuff for B
       after_create :do_something
    end
  end
end
```